# JPA Subquery criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a Person class, and a Car class.

```
class Person {
    long id;
    Set<Car> cars;
}

class Car{
    long id;
    Person owner;
    boolean isSold;
}
```

`em.createQuery("SELECT P FROM Person P WHERE P.id = 1")` will return a Person with all his cars.

However, I would like to get a Person with id 1, with their cars which is not yet sold.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: you need to usesql join between person table and car table

Comment: I dont know JPA well, but simlpy going from the SQL point of view: Use the implicit INNER JOIN: `SELECT P FROM Person P, Car C WHERE P.id = 1 AND C.isSold=false`

Comment: You mean "I would like to get all Cars owned by Person with id 1 where the car is not sold". You CANNOT get Person with id 1 with its "cars" field just containing non-sold cars (since if Person with id 1 has sol cars then they will be included as well). Post what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

You can get it two ways:

1.Create another sql query:

```
SELECT c.id, c.idOwner, c.isSold FROM Person p join Car c on p.id = c.carId where c.isSold = false and p.id = 1;
```

2.Create getter and setters

```
class Person {
  long id;
  Set<Car> cars;

  public long getId() {
      return id;
  }

  public void setId(long id) {
      this.id = id;
  }

  public Set<Car> getCars() {
      return cars;
  }

  public void setCars(Set<Car> cars) {
      this.cars = cars;
  }
}
```

Now you can ascribe result to Person object.

```
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT P FROM Person P WHERE P.id = 1");
Person person = q.getSingleResult();
Set<Car> cars = person.getCars();
ArrayList<Car> unsoldCars = new ArrayList<Car>();
cars.foreach(car -> { 
 if(car.isSold == false) {
    unsoldCars.add(car);
  } 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to map the entities correctly. I guess you dit it, but if you haven't done it yet, the following mapping might serve the purpose:

```
@Entity
class Person {
    @Id @GeneratedValue private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner")
    Set<Car> cars;

    // getters and setters
}

@Entity
class Car{
    @Id @GeneratedValue private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn( name = "owner_id")
    Person owner;

    boolean isSold;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

Query:

```
  String queryString = "SELECT p FROM Person p join p.cars c where c.isSold = false and p.id = 1";
  TypedQuery<Person> q = em.createQuery(queryString, Person.class);
  Person p = q.getSingleResult();
  Set<Car> unsoldCars = p.getCars();
  // Don't forget exception handling
```

This query will return the person with the `id = 1` and all the cars owned by the person and that are not sold.